# How do I support arguments for my homebrew formula?

Tags: macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I am writing a formula to install some packages and would like to give the user control to install a version of his/her choice.

For example:

brew install git <-version->

I have been trying to find examples on how to implement this in my formula but cannot find any. I am kinda new to ruby so am struggling a bit. Can/how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by Homebrew. You may be interested in the [homebrew-versions tap](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions), which illustrates how Homebrew manages multiple versions of software.

The [Formula Cookbook](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Formula-Cookbook) describes many of the things you can do in a formula, including how to accept options.